# Е и Ё в страдательных причастиях

Tags: причастия

Приведённый и приведенный? Несший или нёсший? Строго ли нормированы в языке правила употребления "е" или "ё" в страдательных причастиях? Есть ли какой-то принцип, по которому отбирается та или иная буква или отбор во всех случаях можно свести к традиции?

Comment: В процессе исторического развития языка становится нормой - отбирается.

Answer (score 2):

Правило:

> Если   страдательное   причастие   прошедшего
>    времени    образуется   от   глагола   на  -ать- 
>   (  -ять-  ),  то   перед    суффиксом   причастия 
>    пишется   буква а   или   я:
>
> послать   –   посланный,   усеять   –   усеянный.
>
> Если   причастие   образовано   от   глагола   на
>    - еть, -ить, -сти, -чь,  то  в  суффиксе  пишется   е 
>     (  ё  ):
>
> видеть   –   увиденный
>   осушить   –   осушенный.
>
> **Под   ударением   е   в   суффиксе   страдательных   причастий    переходит   в   ё:**
>
> прекратить   –   прекращённый,   наградить   –   награждённый.
>
> **Буква   ё   сохраняется   в   суффиксе
>
>   страдательных   причастий  и  после   шипящих   под   ударением:**
>
> сражённый,  вскипячённый, освещённый.

Переход [е] в [‘о] происходил в положении после мягких согласных перед твердыми (мягкость предшествующего согласного при этом сохранялась). Если в современном русском литературном языке переход [е] в [‘o] наблюдается только в ударном слоге, то исконно такое
изменение [е] в [‘о], как предполагается, не было связано с положением [е] под ударением.

Старая книжная традиция предполагала произнесение слов с е под ударением после мягких согласных (утомле'нный, сле'зный, коленопреклоне'нный). Так, например, у Пушкина находим раскаленный, а не раскалённый:

В пустыне чахлой и скупой,

На почве, зноем раскаленной,

Анчар, как грозный часовой,

Стоит – один во всей вселенной.
(«Анчар»)

Переход Е в О наиболее регулярно отсутствует в церковно-славянских по происхождению причастиях и прилагательных с суффиксом -енн-, распространившихся **в высоком стиле** литературного языка в XVIII—XIX вв. и **выступающих часто в виде стилистического варианта:** погребенный, убиенный, обагренный, потаенный, согбенный, незабвенный, благословенный, неприкосновенный, сокровенный и др.

Однако с течением времени возобладала общая тенденция произнесения о и в этих словах. В нормализаторской практике наших дней возникла парадоксальная ситуация: словарям приходится теперь оберегать не только традиционное произношение с е от вторжения варианта с о (ле'ска, опе'ка), но и защищать уже также ставшее традицией произношение с о (жёлчь, белёсый). Это как бы обратное направление в развитии произношения обусловлено, по-видимому, в первую очередь графическим восприятием напечатанного слова с буквой е.

Правила употребления букв е–ё сводятся прежде всего к предупреждению от неверного опознавания слова: все и всё, узнает и узнаёт, небо и нёбо, железка и желёзка, крестный (ход) и крёстный (отец), истекший (год) и истёкший (кровью), но не служит для указания на правильное произношение читаемого слова.

Следует предпочесть, например: манёвры, манёвренный, блёклый, блёкнуть, поблёкший, белёсый, а также твёрже (тверже – неправильно).

Причастия ушедший, приведший, забредший произносятся с гласным [е] (после твёрдых шипящих – [э]), а причастия плётший, заплётший, а также принёсший, привёзший – с гласным [о].

Comment: Как я понимаю, наблюдается постепенное вытеснение буквой Ё буквой Е? А ежели сохраняется Е, то это обусловлено графическим восприятием слова? С разнозначными словами понятно. Но ведь есть и обширная группа однозначных. Как в них определять правильное произношение? Только запомнить? Я должен знать заранее, что "умерший", а не "умёрший"?

Comment: Вероятно, да, запомнить прежде всего произношение или обратиться к словарю. Не думаю, что Вы напишете умёрший (умереть -. умер - умерший), тогда как ударение на первый слог иногда встречается, но это ошибка, верно - умЕрший, но мёртвый в отличие от церковного мертвый. Традицию забывать не следует. Вот целое любительское исследование от Галины Москаленко: 
 https://shkolazhizni.ru/school/articles/16849/